# notBoxPlot in Matlab - how to plot 4 barplots?

Tags: matlab

I have four sets of data and I'm trying to use notBoxPlot to plot them. Unfortunately, notBoxPlot takes in only two inputs, so I'm having trouble figuring out a way to plot all 4 of them on a single graph.

I tried using "hold on" but the 2nd notBoxPlot barplots overlap the first ones.

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete, verifiable example:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  This will help people answer your question!

Comment: Can you provide more info about your data/code?  You're using notBoxPlot from FileExchange?  Just with the info you provided and a quick scan over the notBoxPlot file, it seems you should be able to plot as many sets of data as the columns of input variable 'y'